# Pandas: using SimpleImputer transforms dataframe into a series?

Tags: pandas

I've got a dataframe with some NaNs. I'd like to fill them with the column mean values. It's all good but after applying the code below, the dataframe seems to have been change to a series, all values suddenly have precision of lots of places after the decimal point, the column names of the original dataframe have been lost and replaced with 0,1,2, I know I can recreate/reset all of this but is it possible to use SimpleImputer without changing the underlying structure/type of the data?

```
impute = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
impute.fit(dfn)
dfn_mean=impute.transform(dfn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use only pandas solution with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and `mean`, where by default are omited non numeric columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,np.nan,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,np.nan,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

df = df.fillna(df.mean())
print (df)
   A  B    C  D    E  F
0  a  4  7.0  1  5.0  a
1  b  5  8.0  3  3.0  a
2  c  4  9.0  5  6.0  a
3  d  5  4.0  7  9.0  b
4  e  5  6.2  1  5.4  b
5  f  4  3.0  0  4.0  b
```

Your solution should be changed with processing only floats columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
impute = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')

c = df.select_dtypes(np.floating).columns
df[c] = impute.fit_transform(df[c])
print (df)
   A  B    C  D    E  F
0  a  4  7.0  1  5.0  a
1  b  5  8.0  3  3.0  a
2  c  4  9.0  5  6.0  a
3  d  5  4.0  7  9.0  b
4  e  5  6.2  1  5.4  b
5  f  4  3.0  0  4.0  b
```

Or only numeric, but then integers columns are converted to floats:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
impute = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')

c = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[c] = impute.fit_transform(df[c])
print (df)
   A    B    C    D    E  F
0  a  4.0  7.0  1.0  5.0  a
1  b  5.0  8.0  3.0  3.0  a
2  c  4.0  9.0  5.0  6.0  a
3  d  5.0  4.0  7.0  9.0  b
4  e  5.0  6.2  1.0  5.4  b
5  f  4.0  3.0  0.0  4.0  b
```

Comment: Thanks. I think your Pandas solution is simpler. A question: is it possible to limit the fillna to only certain columns?

Comment: @Wasteland - Sure, You can use `df = df.fillna(df[['col1','col2','col3']].mean())`